Summary statistics from selection in attribute table
I am trying to calculate statistics (sum) from a selection in the attribute table. I know how to calculate the sum from an entire field, but not from a specific selection. In this case, I have a vector layer of different type of soils, and every polygon has their surface area in the attribute layer. I'm trying to figure out the total surface for each type of soil.

Method 1:
In QGIS, you have the statistics button. When you click on it it will open the Statistics panel:

Tick on Selected Features if you want to calculate the statistics for your selection only.

Method 2:
Use the Group Stats Plugin that can calculate your statistics based on groups:

Here is a link for the tutorial: Tutorial Page

Try the Statistics by Categories tool.  You can find it in:
Processing > Toolbox > Vector Analysis
Here's the process:

Make your selection
Select the layer name (1 below) and check the Selected features only box
Select the “area” field in Field to calculate statistics (2 below)
“Soil type” goes in Field(s) with categories (3 below)

Voila!  Total surface area by each soil type is output.

